# GWT sliding side panel

Tags: gwt, panel, slide

I am interested in how would you approach creating sliding side panel in GWT? (i.e. social networks sliding panel on the left of this page: http://www.inc.com/articles/2011/03/how-19-year-old-daniel-gross-is-taking-on-google-with-greplin.html)

What kind of events should I handle?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of stuff can be done entirely with CSS. Have a look at the css properties `position: relative` (for the initial position), `position: fixed` as well as `top` and `left` properties when the user scrolls.