# Exempt some elements from Modalness

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, modal-dialog

My application has modal dialogs in it, and also a feedback widget that sticks off the side of the page at all times. I'd like users to be able to click the feedback widget without canceling the modal dialog. In effect, I'd like to exempt the feedback widget from the modal rules of the app.

What's the best way to achieve this?  I'm using GWT 2.3, and I'm happy to drill down into whatever layer of abstraction I need to.

Comment: Do you mean a panel that 'follows' the scrolling like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167286/gwt-sliding-side-panel/5168490#5168490?

Comment: No, I think a combination of Jason's and Thomas' answers will be the solution. I just want to achieve a sort of semi-modality, where all normal modes of operation are suspended _except_ the "feedback" mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Modal" popups actually don't behave well in GWT; that's why `setGlassEnabled` has been added. If you use `setGlassEnabled`, you can then simply set a higher `z-index` to any element that you want to appear on top of the glass pane, it's *just CSS*.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `PopupPanel` source it appears that adding your feedback widget as an [auto-hide partner](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#addAutoHidePartner%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29) will do what you want:

```
Widget feedback;
DialogBox modal = new DialogBox(false, true);
modal.addAutoHidePartner(feedback.getElement());
modal.show();
```

Comment: I think this is half of the solutio